# sorting strings by numerical value in the string in python

Tags: python, string, sorting

For a list with these strings, I am trying to sort them by the numbers preceding the "_" character.

```
my_lst = ['25_mg', '2_mg', '200_mg', '10_mg', '5_mg']
```

Tried several sorts like this one:  print(test.sort(key = lambda x: x.split('_')[0]))

But, the list doesn't sort as expected which would be like this:

```
my_lst = ['2_mg', '5_mg', '10_mg', '25_mg', '200_mg']
```

Comment: `lambda x: int(x.split('_')[0])` typecast to `int`. Otherwise it's a string and it's compared character by character lexicographicallly.

Answer (score 1):

Your sort will order the strings "25", "2", etc, so everything that starts with a "1" will come first. It seems you want to sort by their actual numerical value, so change it to

```
my_lst.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.split('_')[0]))
print(my_lst)
```

which gives

```
['2_mg', '5_mg', '10_mg', '25_mg', '200_mg']
```